# how do i cipher user's input in caesar cs50?

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

i'm stuck on the last part of Caesar in Pset2. what i'm supposed to do is cipher the user's input (plaintext) based on the key they gave in the beginning. this is the formula i have to use:

ciphertext's i'th character = (plaintext's i'th character + key) % 26

i've been stuck on this for almost 2 weeks and i still don't know how to implement the formula (ik how it works though). this is what i have done so far, but obviously it has errors that i don't know how to fix.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])                           //command line argument
{

  if (argc != 2)                                            //correct argument count
  {
    printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
  }


  for (int i = 0 ; argv[1][i] ; i++)
  {

    if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))                             //if digit = correct
    {
      printf("success\n");
    }

    else if(isalpha(argv[1][i]))                           // if letter= wrong
    {
      printf ("usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
    }

  }

  string plaintext = get_string("plaintext;");

  for( int m = 0 ; m<strlen(plaintext) ; m++)
  {
    string ciphertext[m];
    
    if(isupper(plaintext[m]))
    {
     ciphertext[m] = (plaintext[m] + argv[1]) % 26;
    }
    else if(islower(plaintext[m]))
    {
      ciphertext[m] = (plaintext[m] + argv[1]) % 26;
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", ciphertext[m]);
  }


}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be `ciphertext's i'th character = (plaintext's i'th character + i'th char of key) % 26`

Comment: Instead of `ciphertext's i'th character = (plaintext's i'th character + key) % 26` I would expect `ciphertext's i'th character = (plaintext's i'th character - 'a' + key) % 26 +'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[1]` is a string (char*). I expect the compiler is complaining about adding an int to a char*. From the hints in [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/caesar/):

> Recall that the `atoi` function converts a string that looks like a number into that number.